# Optimizing Linq query: order by

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq query and I found that the LastRenewed call where I do a join and order by takes almost a minute. Taking the order by out reduces the query time by 30 seconds. Is there a way I can optimize the LastRenewed call?

```
from stats in db.Stats 
group stats by stats.Id into st
join logs in db.Logs on st.Key equals logs.Id
select new
{
    //bunch of queries
    ... 
    LastRenewed = (from books in (db.Books.Where(x => x.BookId == st.Key))
                   join customer in db.Customers on books.Id equals customer.Id
                   orderby customer.LastRenewed descending
                   select customer.LastRenewed)
                  .FirstOrDefault(),
    ...
}
```

Comment: How much data are you returning?

Comment: Do you have an index on the LastRenewed column?

Comment: If you are querying alot of data I would use context.SQLQuery<YourObject> and call a stored procedure to get your data. EF is cool and all for uncomplicated queries, but the SQL Engline will inevitably run MUCH faster in some circumstances.

Comment: Show the relevant db schema

Answer (score -1):

Take `db.Books.Where(x => x.BookId == st.Key)` and store it somehwere outside the query then use it like so:

```
object books = `db.Books.Where(x => x.BookId == st.Key)`
LastRenewed = (from books in (books))
               join customer in db.Customers on books.Id equals customer.Id
               orderby customer.LastRenewed descending
               select customer.LastRenewed)
              .FirstOrDefault(),
```

This should help a little.

Comment: How would that help?  It's just going to get turned into SQL in the end and the issue is almost definitely on the DB side.

Comment: Yes, your absolutely right. I should have read the question more clearly. Thanks for the clarification. Can't see what is going on on the database side, although if it is EF, I have found that it runs slower than a standard sql reader call to the database.